# compile C file with NDK on Android studio 0.5.7

Tags: android, android-ndk

I just started to discover android and I would like to use NDK with android studio 0.5.7.
I'm using ndk-r9d.

Therefore, I've followed the tutorial http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=okLKfxfbz40

In my project, I had the known problem `NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null`. I could resolve that by compiling manually the native code.

But in this tutorial, he's able to compile C file directly with gradle and android studio (0.5.1). (He's on windows)

Is there now a better way to make gradle works with NDK instead of compiling everything manually ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've actually made this video.
You can get more background information on this from my article: [Android Studio NDK integration](http://ph0b.com/android-studio-gradle-and-ndk-integration/)

`NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null` is normal with Android Studio, it compiles without it by generating its own Android.mk file and using absolute paths.

The way with android studio 0.5.7 and any OS hasn't changed. If you have sources inside jni/ folder they should get compiled automatically.

Comment: Was a strupid error. It was just that ndk doesn't support space in the path unlike sdk.

Comment: why you need to create JNI folder through command line, if I chose not to do it through command line how can I do it otherwise?
Since android studio 1.3 is out

Comment: Android Studio 1.3 still doesn't include full C/C++ editing support in the current previews. You don't need to go through command line, you can already do a right click on src/main folder and create a new directory that you name jni.